# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline - Execute stages on multiple nodes simultaneously

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to execute pipeline stages on multiple nodes simultaneously. If any of the stage fails on any of the node then stages related to that node should fail and other nodes should continue their execution of the stages.

Eg:
I have four nodes - 1,2,3,4 and four stages - A,B,C,D
Each node should start their stage execution from A till D
Likewise, all nodes should start at a time
If node 2 fails, then other nodes should not stop their execution

Please help me on how to start with this design

NOTE: I do not want to rewrite the same code again in my pipeline